# how to get real time log via perforce api similar to p4v log

Tags: c#, logging, real-time, perforce, p4api.net

I am facing issue with perforce api (.net), as i am unable to pull sync logs in real time.

**- What am I trying to do**

> I am trying to pull real time logs as Sync is triggered using the
>   `Perforce.P4.Client.SyncFiles()` command. Similar to the P4V GUI Logs, which update when we try to sync any files.

**- What is happening now**

> - As the output is generated only after the command is done execution    its not something intended for.
> - Also tried looking into `Perforce.P4.P4Server.RunCommand()`  which does provide    detailed report but only after the execution of the command.
>     Looked into [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28452312/how-to-show-output-for-file-operations-performed-by-perforce-api)

***Reason is*** -

> *I am trying to add a status update to the Tool i am working on which shows which Perforce file is currently being sync'd.*

Please advise. Thanks in Advance.

-Bharath

Comment: This comment sounds very useful: "... the repository.Connection contains also other interesting delegates to hook: .CommandEcho, .Errorreceived, .InfoResultReceived,"  Did you try those?  I'd expect `InfoResultReceived` to be what you're looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the C++ client API (which is what P4V is built on), the client receives an `OutputInfo` callback (or `OutputStat` in `tag`ged mode) for each file as it begins syncing.

Looking over the [.NET documentation](https://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/p4api.net/p4api.net_reference/Index.html) I think the equivalents are the `P4CallBacks.InfoResultsDelegate` and `P4CallBacks.TaggedOutputDelegate` which handle events like `P4Server.InfoResultsReceived` etc.

Comment: Thanks @sam. InfoResultsReceived gives information like, user logged in and client workspace created(saved) but doesnt provide when files are being sync'd.

Comment: Quick Update, TaggedOutput delegate gives raw information, which we can format and get the intended output.
downside is, it also prints out lot of other p4 actions.

Comment: Sadly, the new API 2018.x has broken the TaggedOutput, It doesnt error, but it also doesnt output . Please suggest.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up with the same issue, and I struggled quite a bit to get it to work, so I will share the solution I found:

First, you should use the P4Server class instead of the Perforce.P4.Connection. They are two classes doing more or less the same thing, but when I tried using the P4.Connection.TaggedOutputReceived events, I simply got nothing back. So instead I tried with the P4Server.TaggedOutputReceived, and there, finally, I got the TaggedOutput just like I wanted.

So, here is a small example:

```
P4Server p4Server = new P4Server(cwdPath); //In my case I use P4Config, so no need to set user or to login, but you can do all that with the p4Server here.
p4Server.TaggedOutputReceived += P4ServerTaggedOutputEvent;
p4Server.ErrorReceived += P4ServerErrorReceived;
bool syncSuccess=false;
try
{
    P4Command syncCommand = new P4Command(p4Server, "sync", true, syncPath + "\\...");
    P4CommandResult rslt = syncCommand.Run();
    syncSuccess=true;
    //Here you can read the content of the P4CommandResult
    //But it will only be accessible when the command is finished.
}
catch (P4Exception ex) //Will be caught only when the command has failed
{
    Console.WriteLine("P4Command failed: " + ex.Message);
}
```

And the method to handle the error messages or the taggedOutput:

```
private void P4ServerErrorReceived(uint cmdId, int severity, int errorNumber, string data)
{
    Console.WriteLine("P4ServerErrorReceived:" + data);
}

private void P4ServerTaggedOutputEvent(uint cmdId, int ObjId, TaggedObject Obj)
{
    Console.WriteLine("P4ServerTaggedOutputEvent:" + Obj["clientFile"]); //Write the synced file name.
    //Note that I used this only for a 'Sync' command, for other commands, I guess there might not be any Obj["clientFile"], so you should check for that.
}
```